# How do I detokenize '\texttt{%>%}'

Tags: comments, typewriter, detokenize

I have a command:

```
\newcommand{\help}[2]{
  \href{https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/#1/functions/#2}{\texttt{?\detokenize{#2}}}
}
```

and another

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

They don't work with

```
\help{magritrr}{%>%}
```

or

```
\code{%>%}
```

Comment: Commands like `\url` change the catcode of `%` at execution and change back after they finish the job. Maybe you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Symbol 1 suggested in a comment, changing the catcode of `%` before the argument is absorbed is essential.  And then making sure it is changed back when done, is equally essential.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\code}{\catcode`\%=12 \codeaux}
\newcommand\codeaux[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\catcode`\%=14}
\begin{document}
\code{%>%}

Test% if these print or not
\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative approach is to use grouping to negate the catcode change upon exit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\code}{\begingroup\catcode`\%=12 \codeaux}
\newcommand\codeaux[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\code{%>%}

Test% if these print or not
\end{document}
```

Comment: it should be `\newcommand\codeaux[1]{\endgroup\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}`. Your version doesn't close the group.

Comment: Should there be an `\endgroup` in codeaux? If so, the change back is unnecessary. Also, why not simply use \verb".."?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yes, thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, will fix

Comment: So is this then the response to the first part of my question: ```\newcommand{\help}[2]{\href{https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/#1/functions/#2}{\code{?}\code{#2}}}}``

Comment: My @mk9y response was incorrect (extra '}'). Instead: ```\newcommand{\help}[2]{\href{https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/#1/functions/#2}{\code{?#2}}}```

Comment: @mk9y No, that will not suffice.  Why?  Because, if you call `\help` in that way, the 2nd argument will be "absorbed" by `\help`, not by `\codeaux`, and the catcode will be wrong.  You essentially need to write it as `\help` changes the catcode and calls on `\helpaux` which absorbs the two arguments.